# Kubernetes Ingress load balancer rewrites everything to index; why?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

**TL;DR** for some reason every http service seems to have the path rewritten as `/`

I'm pretty new to Kubernetes and trying to set up an ingress load balancer.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.6", GitCommit:"4bc5e7f9a6c25dc4c03d4d656f2cefd21540e28c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-14T06:55:55Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7+", GitVersion:"v1.7.6-gke.1", GitCommit:"407dbfe965f3de06b332cc22d2eb1ca07fb4d3fb", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-27T21:21:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I'm setting everything up in Google Container Engine (GKE)

It's partially working, which is a good thing. However, for some reason it's routing everything to my service as if the request is directed at `/`.

What's happening here? My guess is poor configuration.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "ingress-main-ip"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: cert-main
    hosts:
    - api.example.com
  rules:
  - host: api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my_service/*
        backend:
          serviceName: myService
          servicePort: main-port
      - path: /my_service2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: myService2
          servicePort: main-port
```

Whenever I make a request to `api.example.com/my_service/` then myService will register the request as coming from index--no problem.

Same thing with `https://api.example.com/my_service2/` which goes to myService2

But whenever I make a request to `https://api.example.com/my_service/bogus/path/that/should/return/404` then my service seems to think the request is being directed at the `/` path again just as before.

Of course when I run myService locally (which happens to be a Go http server), then it works perfectly fine. **To be especially clear:** running this locally `127.0.0.1/bogus/path/that/should/return/404` *returns a 404 as expected* (and of course other API endpoints also work)

Here's an extremely strange thing: whenever I visit the static IP address directly  (aka ingress-main-ip, let's just say it's 1.2.3.4), for example `http://1.2.3.4/my_service/` or `http://1.2.3.4/my_service2/` it *always* returns a 404 from the GKE default backend, so my services aren't even getting routed to.

Summary:

1. Why are the domain versions of the requests all routing to `/`
2. Why do the direct IP requests not work at all?

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert is right about the second question (Many thanks)

I just figured out the main question, why all my paths seemed to be rewritten to `/`

It turns out that the path is sent to the server with the "path" as specified in the ingress configuration to the actual service.
So for example, when trying to do a GET request to `api.example.com/my_service/my_endpoint`, I was expecting `my_service` to just get the path `/my_endpoint` but it was actually getting the full `/my_service/my_endpoint`

This seems like a pretty bad kubernetes side effect in my opinion, and the path should really be a relative rewrite.

In any case it's fixed now. The reason I "thought" that they were all being rewritten to simply `/` is because for some reason (logic errors I wrote into my code) my multiplexer was capturing every unknown request and sending it to my index controller. Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the 2nd question.

The *extremely strange thing* is due to the HTTP header "Host" matters because you specified it in the **rules** section:

```
rules:
  - host: api.example.com           <----- THIS
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my_service/*
        backend:
          serviceName: myService
          servicePort: main-port
      - path: /my_service2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: myService2
          servicePort: main-port
```

So it's used to route the request to the proper service. If your *service controller* is nginx, so that "host:" is its [*server_name*](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).